# Dismiss view controller to previous view controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I know lots of people may asked this question . i have also find the solution but i am not able to understand what is wrong in my code ?

popcontroller.swift:

```
protocol DataSendDelegate {
    func sendgetattid(pop_att_id: Int, pop_in_time: String)
}
var delegate: DataSendDelegate? = nil

if statuss == "200" {
let send_pop_att_id = att_id
let send_pop_in_time = in_time
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
self.dismiss(animated: true) {                                    
self.delegate?.sendgetattid(pop_att_id: send_pop_att_id, pop_in_time: send_pop_in_time)
}
}
```

In the above code i get the correct value but it does not dismiss and go to next view controller .

attendanceViewController.swift:

```
class attendanceViewController: UIViewController , DataSendDelegate {
func sendgetattid(pop_att_id: Int, pop_in_time: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.inTimeTextField.text = pop_in_time
            self.get_att_id = pop_att_id
            self.in_time_button.isEnabled = false
            self.out_time_button.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let popVC = segue.destination as? PopUpViewController
        {
            popVC.popEmailID = att_emp_id
            popVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update from your comment:** 
 You didn't present viewController. You have pushed some view controller. So Just pop it. discard the `dismiss`

```
self.delegate?.sendgetattid(pop_att_id: send_pop_att_id, pop_in_time: send_pop_in_time)
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Ok I will try this method @Mani

Comment: it worked .. it worked very slowly transition was slow . thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you did `self.present(ViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` from the previous ViewController to show the current viewcontroller, you must do

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {                                    
      self.delegate?.sendgetattid(pop_att_id: send_pop_att_id, pop_in_time: send_pop_in_time)
}
```

or if you did `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController, animated: true)` you must do `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`

Comment: I am not doing anything like the thing which you said. I have pushed the view controller to next using segue.

Comment: then you need to do `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`